# Compare lists and add missing

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have 8 Spreadsheets on one workbook. The first one is a weekly overall view. The other seven are broken into days. Each day lists some names of people that came on site. So Monday might have Joe, John, and Jack visit. These are the values in A1, A2 and A3 on Monday's sheet. Tues might have Joe again, then Ryan then Andrew. So they would make up the A1, A2 and A3 values of Tuesday's worksheet, and so on and so forth.

The overall spreadsheet needs to show all names for the week, but not duplicate any of them. So in the Overall sheet, I would like to see something like:

```
Joe
John
Jack
Ryan
Andrew
```

So no names are duplicated. I'd like to do this without macros if possible. The formula that I had begun to create would get extremely long by the time you go the the tenth person or so. It involved `=IF(AND( ),IF(AND( ), IF(AND...` which went for each cell that could potentially have a name on day 1 - I was then going to have a rap it into check for anything in day 2 etc,. You can see how this would get really long.

Any help is appreciated.

EDIT:
The following formula compares two lists and only puts in unique names in a new list:

```
=IFERROR(IFERROR(INDEX(Monday, MATCH(0, COUNTIF($C$1:C1, Monday), 0)),INDEX(List2, MATCH(0, COUNTIF($C$1:C1, List2), 0))), "")
```

(you need to hit ctrl-shift-enter when putting it in a cell so it can work with ranges)

but I don't understand it enough to adapt it to use it across 7 lists.
Any ideas?

Comment: It can be done easily with VBA -- cycle through the sheets, add the names to a Collection object.  If you use the name as a key, it will reject any duplicates.  Then put all the names on your Weekly sheet.  If you want to avoid VBA, copy all the names onto the weekly sheet, then use the `Remove Duplicates` command.  Or, depending on the nature of your data, consider a Pivot Table

Comment: Thank you for the response. If I use the Remove Duplicates command, it only does it once. This document is meant to be dynamic, so I can add to it on a daily basis and it updates the list as I go.

Comment: Well, you can run it every day when you update the list; even a VBA macro would have to be run or triggered when new information is added.

Comment: You see, the length of your worksheet function is why VBa is often a better choice! Any way, it's totally cool to answer your own question but please do so in a different post. Please add yours as an answer and let me know when you do so I can delete the post I provided.

Comment: VBA could trigger every time a cell changes in the range and then run through it.

Answer (score 0):

OP left the answer in the question!

```
=IFERROR( IFERROR( IFERROR( IFERROR( IFERROR( IFERROR( IFERROR( INDEX(ThurNames, MATCH(0, COUNTIF($B$2:B2, ThurNames), 0)), INDEX(FriNames, MATCH(0,COUNTIF($B$2:B2, FriNames), 0))), INDEX(SatNames, MATCH(0, COUNTIF($B$2:B2, SatNames), 0))), INDEX(SunNames, MATCH(0, COUNTIF($B$2:B2, SunNames), 0))), INDEX(MonNames, MATCH(0, COUNTIF($B$2:B2, MonNames), 0))), INDEX(TueNames, MATCH(0, COUNTIF($B$2:B2, TueNames), 0))), INDEX(WedNames, MATCH(0, COUNTIF($B$2:B2, WedNames), 0))), "")
```

That's right, 7 nested iferror statements. If you use this, don't forget to hit ctrl + shift + enter instead of just enter when you are done.

Comment: Should I have put it in a comment?

Comment: No add it as an answer.  I will then delete this one

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to do this with nested IFERROR statements. I hope this helps more people than just me.

=IFERROR( IFERROR( IFERROR( IFERROR( IFERROR( IFERROR( IFERROR( INDEX(ThurNames, MATCH(0, COUNTIF($B$2:B2, ThurNames), 0)), INDEX(FriNames, MATCH(0,COUNTIF($B$2:B2, FriNames), 0))), INDEX(SatNames, MATCH(0, COUNTIF($B$2:B2, SatNames), 0))), INDEX(SunNames, MATCH(0, COUNTIF($B$2:B2, SunNames), 0))), INDEX(MonNames, MATCH(0, COUNTIF($B$2:B2, MonNames), 0))), INDEX(TueNames, MATCH(0, COUNTIF($B$2:B2, TueNames), 0))), INDEX(WedNames, MATCH(0, COUNTIF($B$2:B2, WedNames), 0))), "")

NB: This is important, once you put this into your formula bar - end it by pressing ctrl-shift-enter or it won't work.

ctrl-shift-enter tells formulas it needs to work across ranges of data.